# Difference between bytes() and b''

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytestream

I have the following `str`:
`"\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0_RootKit.com_63k.txt"`

This comes from a filename: `Расшифровка_RootKit.com_63k.txt`

My problem is a cannot reverse the first `str` to the second one. I have tried a few things, using `en/decode()`, `bytes()`, *etc* but I did not manage.

One thing I noticed was b'' and bytes() have different outputs:

```py
path = "\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0_RootKit.com_63k.txt"
bpath = bytes(path, "UTF-8")
print(bpath.decode("UTF-8"))
print(b"\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0_RootKit.com_63k.txt".decode('utf8'))
```

Results:

```
Ð Ð°ÑÑÐ¸Ñ
         ÑÐ¾Ð²ÐºÐ°_RootKit.com_63k.txt
Расшифровка_RootKit.com_63k.txt
```

So I wonder what is the difference between `b''` and `bytes()`; maybe it will help me solving my problem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You may want to use solution with `latin1`, scroll to that answer firstly. This answer works if you accidentally copied bytes content and pasted as a string.*

If you want to convert them back to bytes, use the following code:

```
In [22]: path = "\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0_RootKit.com_63k.txt"

In [23]: bytes(map(ord, path)).decode('utf-8')
Out[23]: 'Расшифровка_RootKit.com_63k.txt'
```

Explanation is quite simple, lets use the first character from the string:

```
In [40]: '\xd0'
Out[40]: 'Ð'

In [41]: b'\xd0'
Out[41]: b'\xd0'
```

As you can see, string converts `\xd0` to a unicode character with number `0xd0`, while bytes just interprets this as a single byte.

UTF-8 uses the following mask for all characters between `U+0080` and `U+07FF`: `110xxxxx` for the first byte and `10xxxxxx` for the second byte. This is exactly what you gets when directly converting that string to bytes:

```
In [43]: [bin(x) for x in '\xd0'.encode('utf-8')]
Out[43]: ['0b11000011', '0b10010000']
```

And the actual symbol code is `00011` + `010000` (concatenation, not addition), which is `0xd0`:

```
In [44]: hex(int('00011010000', 2))
Out[44]: '0xd0'
```

To get this number from a character we can use `ord`:

```
In [45]: hex(ord('\xd0'))
Out[45]: '0xd0'
```

And then just applying it to the whole string and converting it back to bytes:

```
In [46]: bytes(map(ord, path)).decode('utf-8')
Out[46]: 'Расшифровка_RootKit.com_63k.txt'
```

Note that if your string character does not fit in byte for some reason the code above will raise an error:

```
In [47]: bytes([ord(chr(256))])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-5555e18dbece> in <module>
----> 1 bytes([ord(chr(256))])

ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)
```

Comment: That is awesome and quite elegant! Thanks.

Comment: @Chocorean updated the answer with explanation and a note about invalid string

Comment: And btw I think the answer with `latin1` is the real answer for this question

Answer (score 3):

`b''` is a prefix, that causes the following string to be interpreted as a `bytes`-type object. The `bytes` function takes a string and returns a `bytes` object.

```
print(b"\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0_RootKit.com_63k.txt".decode
```

This works, because you are decoding a bytes object.

```
path = "\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0_RootKit.com_63k.txt"
bpath = bytes(path, "UTF-8")
print(bpath.decode("UTF-8"))
```

This does not work as intended, because you are treating `path` as a string, then converting it into a bytes object, then trying to decode what comes out.

Comment: Right, I now understand. Thank you

Comment: This doesn't explain anything. It would not be strange even if those two results are the same. The Python string and b'' interpret differently, that's the reason the results are different. Please see @awesoon's answer.

Answer (score 2):

To convert your string, just encode it to bytes using 'latin1' that has a 1 to 1 mapping between bytes and characters, and decode using 'utf8':

```
s = "\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0_RootKit.com_63k.txt"

s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')

# 'Расшифровка_RootKit.com_63k.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

`path` variable is a string (not Bytes).
When you use the method `bytes()` you are decoding it to bytes which will return   `b'\xc3\x90\xc2\xa0\xc3\x90\xc2\xb0\xc3\x91\xc2\x81\xc3\x91\xc2\x88\xc3\x90\xc2\xb8\xc3\x91\xc2\x84\xc3\x91\xc2\x80\xc3\x90\xc2\xbe\xc3\x90\xc2\xb2\xc3\x90\xc2\xba\xc3\x90\xc2\xb0_RootKit.com_63k.txt'`

But when your are writing `b"\xd0\xa0\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0_RootKit.com_63k.txt"` you are refering to the Bytes value of `Расшифровка_RootKit.com_63k.txt`

Comment: Right. Is there a way to turn my string into bytes without decoding it ? (I know this has not a lot of sense-)

Comment: As you say " this has not a lot of sense". I'm still struggling to understand what you are trying to do? what is your input and what is you desired output?

Comment: The file I'm talking about is uploaded to a flask api, but its name turns into my variable `path`, and flask fails saving the file, so I'm trying to rename it.